# Angular ngx-mqtt – Connect to mqtt broker using user inputted values on a form instead of hard coding values in app.module.ts

Tags: angular, mqtt, mosquitto, broker, submit-button

I’m trying to allow a user to specify connection values to connect to a mosquitto broker via a Angular Material Dialogue Modal though a form, instead of hard coding values into the **app.module.ts**.

So far I’m able to connect to a broker by hard coding the values into the **app.module.ts** file. I'm able to see all my MQTT topics with no issues.

**app.module.ts**

```
 import { NgModule, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { MqttModule, IMqttServiceOptions, IMqttMessage } from "ngx-mqtt";
    import { MqttStatusClientService } from './services/mqtt-status-client.service';
    
    export const MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS: IMqttServiceOptions = 
    {
      hostname: '<IP ADDRESS>', 
      username: 'username', 
      password: 'password', 
      port: 9001
    };
    
    @NgModule({
    declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    ],
    
    imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MqttModule.forRoot(MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS),
    ],
    providers: [MqttStatusClientService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

However I would like to remove this way hard coding values to connect to the broker and instead allow a user to fill out a form to input values that are then used to connect to a broker. All within it's own seperate component away from the **app.module.ts**.

Here is my attempt:

**broker-connect.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { MqttService} from "ngx-mqtt";
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
selector: 'app-broker-connect',
templateUrl: './broker-connect.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./broker-connect.component.css']
})
export class BrokerConnectComponent implements OnInit 
{
  constructor(private Form: FormBuilder, private mqtt: MqttService, private    dialogRef: MatDialogRef<BrokerConnectComponent>) { }

BrokerConnectForm = this.Form.group({
brokerName: [''],
brokerUsername: [''],
brokerPassword: [''],
brokerAddress: [''],
brokerPort: ['']
});

brokerName = this.BrokerConnectForm.get('brokerName')?.value
ngOnInit(): void {}

connectToBroker() 
{
  this.mqtt.connect({username: this.BrokerConnectForm.get('brokerUsername')?.value,
  password: this.BrokerConnectForm.get('brokerPassword')?.value,
  hostname: this.BrokerConnectForm.get('brokerAddress')?.value,
  port: this.BrokerConnectForm.get('brokerPort')?.value})

  this.dialogRef.close()
}
```

As you can see here I have a seperate Angular component that contains a form group that contains each of the form inputs to connect to a broker.

When the submit button on the form is pressed the **connectToBroker()** function is invoked.

In this function I’ve attempted to make use of the built in **connect()** method for the **MqttService** which, with the very little documentation available for ngx-mqtt I've found, should allow you to manually connect to a broker by passing in values that are of the format of a IMqttServiceOptions object, much like I did with the **MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS** constant in **app.module.ts**.

However this doesn’t appear to work as I never see my topic detail values, and for some reason I get error messages saying I can't connect to localhost, even though the port number is specified. In my case the port number is **9001**, which is also configured to run over websockets on the mqtt broker. So I can't understand why it's trying to connect to localhost.

This does not occur when I hard code the exact same values into the **MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS** constant in **app.module.ts**.

I also deliberatly put in the wrong broker IP address (into my form) which gives me the same error as below but it say's it can't connect to the actual IP address. But if i pass in the correct broker IP address it gives me the localhost error like below:

[image]

I’m not sure how I might be able to achieve this, there is very little documentation that I could find around ngx-mqtt. I did try to simply pass the user inputted values directly to the **MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS** constant in the **app.module.ts**, but passing values from a modal dialog to other parts of your angular application seems to be difficult and I haven't had success doing that.

In short, I’m trying to connect to an mqtt broker in a seperate component away from the **app.module.ts**, via user input when a form button is submitted, instead of hard coding the values in the **app.module.ts**.

[Here is a link](https://sclausen.github.io/ngx-mqtt/) to the ngx-mqtt documentation.

Comment: Do you understand that localhost means the computer that the program is running on? In this case that would mean the computer the browser is running on? Which is likely not the computer the broker is running on.

Comment: @romkey Yes I do understand, in my app.module.ts I've just used localhost as a placeholder, so I'm not exposing IP addresses. And the localhost in the last image doesn't matter as I still get the same error even when i'm using a proper IP address to a legit mqtt server. I'll update my question to specify that.

Comment: Okay. A shocking number of people don’t know this.

Comment: Are you setting a port number for the broker? the image at the end implies it's connecting to port 80 (which would normally be the http server)

Comment: @hardillb I am setting the port to 9001 which is configured in the mqtt broker for websockets, so my Angular front end works. The strange thing is that if i use the hard coded approach in the app.module.ts and set the values (including port number) in the export const MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS: IMqttServiceOptions. I get no connection errors and it works no problem. However If I try to manually pass in values from a user input form and pass it to the ngx-mqtt connect method outside of the app.module.ts. Then it doesn't work and I get connection error pointing to localhost. I don't understand.

Comment: @hardillb I've also updated my question to make it clearer regarding the error messages.

Comment: @SneakyShrike were you able to resolve this issue, i am also in same boat

Comment: @SneakyShrike i am able to find anwer for same. i.e. when you initially created  mqtt: MqttService , its in constructor to create a service and connect it. To stop it from happening you have to pass with   mqttServiceOpts: IMqttServiceOptions = {
    connectOnCreate: false,
    hostname: 'vip.abc.com',
    port: 8090,
    path: '/mqtt',
    protocol: 'wss',
    username: 'dia',
    password: 'dia',
    connectTimeout: 60,
    keepalive: 0,
    clean: true,
  }  See clealrly you need to have    connectOnCreate: false , which is important. Hope it helps.

Comment: @InderRSingh Sorry I didn't get back to you. It looks you might be on to something. I'll try what you suggested and get back to you. Thanks for your efforts. I havn't really looked into it much since I've been busy, but it will be good to have another crack at it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the inteded way to use the library is to initially configure MQTT for the root

```
MqttModule.forRoot({...})
```

there it's very important to configure

```
connectOnCreate: false
```

after that, you can inject

```
mqttService: MqttService
```

in any component/service and connect with custom options via

```
this.mqttService.connect({...});
```

which then gets merged with the initial configuration.

just stumbled over this so no guarantee it really works but so far for me it does